# Add void / blank line between print()

Tags: r

I built a function that print results in R console.
The function works within a loop.
Several prints are made when the function is used.
I'd like to add void/space line between printed results

thx!

short example of data and working loop :

```
test <- c("A","B","C")

for (i in 1:length(test)){
  
  print(test[i])
  print("")
  
}
```

actual output :

```
[1] "A"
[1] ""
[1] "B"
[1] ""
[1] "C"
[1] ""
```

desired output :

```
[1] "A"

[1] "B"

[1] "C"
```

Comment: But why? What is the purpose?

Comment: For reading purpose of outputs. Lines printed are long and complex. It would be more clear to have blank space between printed lines.

Comment: Change `print("")` to `cat('\n')`

Comment: Try `for (tt in test) cat(tt, "\n\n")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you'd need two linebreaks to get the double spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments under your question already provide hacks how to solve your problem. Nevertheless, it is worthwhile to mention some problems of your solution.

First, you are using a `for` loop, which is notoriously slow in R. If possible, it is always better to use a builtin vectorized function, e.g. (To add a blank line, just use `"\n\n"` instead of `"\n"`):

```
> cat(test, sep="\n")
A
B
C
```

Moreover, it might generally be preferable, for legibility reasons, to use formatted output with `sprintf` and `cat`, e.g.

```
> for (i in 1:length(test)) {
>    cat(sprintf("test[%i] = %s\n", i, test[i]))
> }
test[1] = A
test[2] = B
test[3] = C
```

And because `sprintf` is a vectorized function, too, the same can be achieved without a `for` loop:

```
> cat(sprintf("test[%i] = %s\n", 1:length(test), test), sep="")
test[1] = A
test[2] = B
test[3] = C
```